# Can't run BAM 2.3.0 server due error 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/github/jamm/MemoryMeter'

Tags: wso2

I'm try to start BAM server on Windows 64 Pro but exception are thrown (with evaluated administrative privileges too)...

> [2013-07-22 15:45:51,575]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2
>   Carbon... [2013-07-22 15:45:51,576]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating
>   System : Windows 8 6.2, amd64 [2013-07-22 15:45:51,576]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home
>   : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre [2013-07-22 15:45:51,576] 
>   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java
>   Version     : 1.7.0_25 [2013-07-22 15:45:51,576]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM
>   : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.25-b01,Oracle Corporation
>
> ...
>
> [2013-07-22 15:45:55,725]  INFO
>   {org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon} -  Classpath:
>   .\lib;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\lib\tools.jar;;.\bin\org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap-4.1.0.jar;.\bin\tcpmon-1.0.jar;.\bin\tomcat-juli-7.0.34.jar;;.\lib\commons-lang-2.6.0.wso2v1.jar
>   [2013-07-22 15:45:55,727]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.utils.CLibrary}
>   -  JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
>
> ...
>
> [2013-07-22 15:45:56,381] ERROR
>   {org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon} -  Exception
>   encountered during startup java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/github/jamm/MemoryMeter   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.(Memtable.java:118)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.DataTracker.init(DataTracker.java:301)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.DataTracker.(DataTracker.java:63)   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.(ColumnFamilyStore.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:329)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.initCf(Table.java:371)     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.(Table.java:304)  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:119)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:97)     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemTable.checkHealth(SystemTable.java:274)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.setup(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.activate(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:353)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.CassandraServerController$1.run(CassandraServerController.java:48)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.github.jamm.MemoryMeter     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    ... 15 more
>   Exception encountered during startup: org/github/jamm/MemoryMeter
>   [2013-07-22 15:45:57,341] ERROR
>   {org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon} -  Exception in
>   thread Thread[OptionalTasks:1,5,main] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/github/jamm/MemoryMeter   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.(Memtable.java:118)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.DataTracker.init(DataTracker.java:301)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.DataTracker.(DataTracker.java:63)   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.(ColumnFamilyStore.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:329)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.initCf(Table.java:371)     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.(Table.java:304)  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:119)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:97)     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table$2.apply(Table.java:578)     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.Table$2.apply(Table.java:575)     at
>   com.google.common.collect.Iterators$9.transform(Iterators.java:845)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.all(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1649)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.MeteredFlusher.countFlushingBytes(MeteredFlusher.java:118)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.db.MeteredFlusher.run(MeteredFlusher.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: I'm running into similar issues with WSO2 Message Broker. I experience a similar issue when running WSO2 MB from within Eclipse (starting a configured server). When starting the server outside of Eclipse the Message Broker server runs fine. Incorporating the "javaagent" fix from the answer below does not resolve the issue, at least with my configuration - Win7 64.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the wso2server.sh file

> -javaagent:"path/to/jamm/jar" \

As an example

> -javaagent:"$CARBON_HOME/repository/components/plugins/jamm_0.2.5.wso2v2.jar"
>   \

Comment: For windows the adjustment to the wso2server.bat file should look more like this: -javaagent:"%CARBON_HOME%\repository\components\plugins\jamm_0.2.5.wso2v2.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Edit `\bin\yajsw\conf\wrapper.conf`.
For WSO2 BAM version 2.5.0 add line to the end of file.

```
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -javaagent:"${cabon_home}\\repository\\components\\plugins\\jamm_0.2.5.wso2v2.jar"
```